# Why this code print value of super class instead of sub class

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class A{
    int a = 10;
}

class B extends A{
    int a= 20;
}

public class C {
    public static void main(String [] args){
         A a = new B();
         System.out.println(a.a);       
        }
}
```

output : 10

How it print value from base class based on above code.

Comment: Because overridden concept only allowed for method not variable in OOPs. And you can hide the variable using super keyword.

Comment: Polymorhpism only exists for functions, not variables.

Comment: If the answers helped you, please consider accepting the answer that you think is the best by clicking on the checkmark!

Answer (score 3):

`B` already inherits `a` from `A`. Doing `int a = 20;` again *hides* the `a` inherited from `A`. This means that an expression of the form `x.a` will only evaluate to 20 if the compile time of `x` is `B`.

To get your expected behaviour, you can reset `a` in the constructor of `B`:

```
class B {
    // no need to redeclare "a" here!
    public B() { a = 20; }
}
```

Comment: or else in the current scenario make sure the object is cast to a `B` type and then access its variable as in `(B) a).a`... Just that it would worsen things in readability and accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a variable of the same name in a subclass like you have done here, its called hiding. The resulting subclass will now actually have both properties.

Please refer below image,

[image]